# List the Id who appeared once only in Relational Algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Let's say there's a table called Winner, with 3 attributes: Name, Gender and Id.

```
Name    Gender   Id
Kevin    Male     8
Kevin    Male     8
Benny    Male     31
Jenny    Female   7
Louie    Male     4
Peter    Male     11
Kevin    Male     2
Jenny    Female   7
Jenny    Female   7
Chris    Male     23
Louie    Female   14
```

Apart from those people who is actually 2 different person but with the same name and those people who have the same name but with different gender, their Id's will be the unique value to identify themselves. If I want to list all the Id's who appeared once only in the list, I am thinking to do something like this:

[image]

Am I expressing it correctly ?

Comment: I'm use to realtional algebra and I have never seen such kind of query with Fcount. Maybe it exists in the extended form... I will try to give you my ideas tomorrow if I have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your formula is trying to say, but in SQL you can achieve the result you want with a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(Id) AS idCount
FROM Winner
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(Id) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for help, the formula I written above is just trying to select those id which showed once only...

Comment: Give my query a try and if it doesn't work then we'll go from there.